# Use Tensorflow model in c++ app

Tags: android, python, c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Apologies in advance for this relatively newbie question. Using Tensorflow, I've trained a neural net in python and I'd like to use it to classify images in a c++ application, which I want to later integrate into an android app.

Today I spent all day working through the Tensorflow Serving tutorial: https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic.

I have everything installed and working, but it's still not obvious to me what to do next. Is TF Serving the right thing to do? Can it be used to integrate a trained TF model into a an application? Or is it just something to build models that can be run from the Terminal?

If TF Serving is not what I need, then where should I look in stead? Is there a simpler way to use trained models cross-platform?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this [section](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic#load-exported-tensorflow-model) in the tutorial for how to load a `SessionBundle` in c++.

Once you have a SessionBundle you can use utilities in [signature.h](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/signature.h) to get a signature (e.g., `GetClassificationSignature`) then run an inference (e.g., `RunClassification`).